# How to check if an object has more than constant number of many to many field objects

Tags: python, django

I have 2 tables say "A" and "B" having ManyToMany relationship with one of the field with table "A", I have created a Model Admin from where I am creating both the tables object.

I have a constraint that I have to create constant number of "B" object for each fields (relation)

I have written below code but it gives an error:
`ValueError: “needs to have a value for field ”id“ before this many-to-many relationship can be used`

```
count = 10
class A(models.Model):
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class B(models.Model):
    field_b = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fields = models.ManyToManyField(A, related_name="bs")

    def save(*args, **kwargs):
        for item in self.fields.all():
            if item.bs.count() > count:
                raise ValidationError(
                    "item count is exeeded"
                )
        return super(B, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Please suggest how to handle this case.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you are calling the related_name from the wrong side fo the relationship.To use the related name you could do `A.bs.all()` which would be a list of all B in the relationship. To call the other way you need to change `item.bs.count()` to `item.A_set.count()`